# add yaml extension to php on using official Alpine Docker image

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux, phpize

I'm using this offical php Docker image: https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/76a1c5ca161f1ed6aafb2c2d26f83ec17360bc68/7.1/alpine/Dockerfile

Now I need to add support for yaml extension, that is not bundled with php.
I see the base image I'm using uses phpize.

I'm trying with this approach:

```
FROM php:7.1.5-alpine

# Install and enable yaml extension support to php
RUN apk add --update yaml yaml-dev
RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net  
RUN pecl install yaml-2.0.0 && docker-php-ext-enable yaml
```

But I get this errors:

```
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20160303
Zend Module Api No:      20160303
Zend Extension Api No:   320160303
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed
ERROR: Service 'php_env' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pecl  install yaml-2.0.0 && docker-php-ext-enable yaml' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What is the most idiomatic docker way to use that image and add that support?

Should I use it as base, or is someway possible to add parameters in order to make wanted extension configurable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alpine uses apk to install packages. The compiling process is complaining about missing `autoconf`, which is found in Alpine's `autoconf` package.

I'd suggest you to run these commands:

```
RUN apk --update yaml-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    g++ make autoconf

RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
RUN pecl install yaml && docker-php-ext-enable yaml

RUN apk del --purge .build-deps
```

If you need to install other non-dev libraries, you can install them in a separate `apk add` command. This procedure will:

1. install the build deps, using `--no-cache` means you're using an updated index and not cached locally (thus no need of `--update` or to save the pkg in the cache). `--virtual` means you're creating a virtual reference for all those packages that can later be deleted (because they're useless after the compiling process)
2. do your stuff with pecl and docker-php-ext-enable
3. delete the previous build deps

If you still encounter any missing dependency, you can see as reference this: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages

Comment: To get `pecl`, readers will need to also do `apk add php7-dev`.

Comment: It's not working for me. I did a phpinfo() and I have in the "Additional .ini files parsed" field the value "/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-yaml.ini", but the extension seems to not be enabled. When I try an example from the php documentation, I get this error message : "Call to undefined function yaml_emit()".
Any ideas ?

Comment: Ok, I feel stupid but I really want to share. I deleted my image and buildt it again, now it's working.
Just building again your image without deleting it before can be source of problems. Indeed, when you build again a same image, it use your old builds to create the new one. I'm kind of a newbie with docker, and I didn't except it to work like this, it's very good to know.
So thanks for your solution, it's now working perfectly !

Comment: Juste something else that I forgot and that you should add in your answer. It's not working if the yaml.so file isn't executable. I had to add this line in my run command : chmod +x $(php-config --extension-dir)/yaml.so
I hope that it will be helpful

Comment: This must be something new: at the time of writing it worked like what I posted out of the box. I'm going to double check it.

Comment: the `apk del --purge .build-deps` breaks it for more me, since it is removing libyaml. I added a `apk add --no-cache yaml` to add the yaml outside of the virtual package to make it work for me

Comment: I get: ERROR: '--update' is not an apk command. See 'apk --help'.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version, at least since 2.0.4, requires yaml-dev to be installed in order to run. So move that to the packages you want to keep in the image. Also, on alpine 3.11 in combination of php-alpine repository, I got the problem that it wants you to add the location of your php.ini file.

just add the following: RUN pear config-set php_ini /etc/php7/php.ini

where you change the path into the path of the location of your php.ini if needed.